# what is the best scenario for implement detection of empty space to park cars in the parking lot?

Tags: arduino, iot, raspberry-pi3

I have a project to detect the empty space for parked cars in the parking lot.

When a person enters the parking lot with a car, he faces a series of green and red lights above each parking lot.
There is a sensor above the head of any park location with 2 green and red lights.

If a car parked in a car, the sensor detects the car and lights its red light to the fullness of the place.
If the sensor detects the location empty, that is, the car did not park under it, it lights up its green light as an empty parking spot.
Now that the driver sees the green lights, he will know where there is space for the park.
Now, I want to know what is the best scenario in your view to implementing this project? Do you recommend using a central system using a robust firewall or using multiple Arduino modules for each sensor?
Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: This should be closed as primary opinion based/too broad. [https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: There are better choices than either of those for IoT, like the modules built for IoT.  But this is primarily opinion based and not suitable for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are different things. Raspberry PI is a computer, arduino is just a microcontroller with peripherals as facilities. Raspberry runs an Operational System inside, Arduino doesn't. Raspberry has a digital-only set of electrical interfaces. Arduino has both analog and digital.

Depend on the project needs one or other is more suitable. Since IoT have infinite scenarios of applications, each one with its requirements and features, in general it is impossible to define what is better for IoT.

Comment: thank you very much. your explanation is clear and I understood the main concept of them.

Comment: You are welcome. Enjoy your IoT projects.